# Нужно ли делать проверку в случае параллельной работы с объектом active record?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Пример желаемого действия в контроллере Ruby on Rails.

```rb
class ElementController < ApplicationController
  def update
    begin
      element = Element.find(params[:id])
      element.counter += 1
      if element.counter == 10
        element.destroy
        redirect_to element_path(element), notice: "Element deleted"
      end
      else
        element.save
        redirect_to element_path(element), notice: "Element updated"
      end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      redirect_to :back, alert: "Failed to update unknown element"
    end
  end
end
```

Чтоб будет если два пользователя параллельно выполнят данное действие, если `element.counter == 9`? Как я понимаю, у одного удалиться, а что будет у другого? Меня беспокоит возможные локи или дедлоки в БД.

Нужно ли писать проверку, удалось ли обновить или удалить элемент?

Возможно ли определить, был ли объект удален другим пользователем, вместо того, что не был найден по ID?

База данных MySQL.